# Using sax writer to create line feeds in a xml 2003 workbook

Tags: excel, progress-4gl

Hi stackoverflow comunity,

using a sax writer with the progress-4gl language i succeeded in creating an a xml 2003 workbook.

My problem began when i wanted to add a linefeed to a cell.
The normal linefeed for excel (in xml) is made using "
", this is a problem because the sax-writer converts & to &amp.

I did find a workaround by using hSax#:write-entity-ref() but this is not ideal because linefeeds are usualy not in the beginning of the string.

example:
this is a
new line.

In this case u need to write this is a, then use hSax#:write-entity-ref() and then write new line. I'd say there has to be a better way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution (took me a while though).

with hSax#:write-fragment() it's possible to write strings without converting special characters.